# disable company-mode completion inside comments

Tags: company-mode

This is something that's been bothering me for  a while. I think I've configured `company-mode` backends wrong as I'm also getting company backends when *inside* comments.

[`Here`](https://github.com/CSRaghunandan/.emacs.d/blob/master/setup-files/setup-company.el) is my `company-mode` config file.
And here is an example of how I enable `company-mode` for specific major modes using a local variable for `company-backends` and adding that to the major mode hook. Like so:-

```
    (defun my-racer-mode-hook ()
      (set (make-local-variable 'company-backends)
           '((company-capf company-files company-yasnippet))))
    (add-hook 'racer-mode-hook 'my-racer-mode-hook)
```

<strike>I configure other major modes very similarly to the snippet above. But, I feel I did a mistake somewhere that's making `company-yasnippet` to pop up in the comments also. Can someone please point out where I did wrong ?</strike>

EDIT: I get completion from all backends inside the comments, not just `company-yasnippet`. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Try adding `:with` before `company-yasnippet`.

Comment: Hi, take a look at the edited question now. and Adding `:with` still gets me completions in the comments

Comment: What is your version of Emacs?

Comment: 25.1-1. running on mac os el capitan

Comment: Ah, I missed that you're using a particular major mode here.

Comment: Umm it happens with every major made that has company enabled :( 
I've no idea how to fix this annoyance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each backend decides whether it works in the given context.

- `company-yasnippet` works everywhere (you can counteract this using the keyword `:with`).
- `company-files` works where it sees a beginning of an existing file name.
- `company-capf` works where one of the elements in `completion-at-point-functions` says it works.

Since around 25.1, `elisp-completion-at-point` refuses to operate inside strings and comments (except when following a backtick, to complete symbol references).

You should probably open an issue at [emacs-racer](https://github.com/racer-rust/emacs-racer/) and ask for `racer-complete-at-point` to behave similarly.